# Proving the sum to product formula with complex numbers starting from the left hand side

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, proof-writing

I've just asked a similar question today [Prove the sum to product formulas with complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4236042/861590) but I was wondering what if we wanted to start with the left hand side instead of the right hand side? Because at the end I want to be able to think, to derive this formula without knowing the outcome, the right hand side, so I'm wondering about how to do it **starting from the left hand side**. My goal: $$\sin x+\sin y=2\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$ Recall the complex definition  of sine and cosine: $$\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$ and $$\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$ Applying both we get after simplifying a bit: $$\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}+e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}{2i}$$ but I don't really know what to do now. I've also tried with the opposite substitution that I used when proving this starting from the right hand side $\alpha=\frac{x+y}{2}$ and $\beta=\frac{x-y}{2}$ but I'm pretty sstuck. I know I have to factor it to get it closer to our goal, but no clue on how to factor this. Any hints?

Comment: Follow the steps in the answer to the other question, in reverse order.

Comment: Alt. hint: $\;\operatorname{cis}(x) = \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{x-y}{2}\right)=\operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\,$, then do something similar for $\,\operatorname{cis}(y)\,$ and add the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, you could "cheat" and use the rhs to inform your factorisation. But that's not what you want.

If you write $a=e^{ix}$ and $b=e^{iy}$, then you have $$\frac{1}{2i}\left(a-\frac 1a + b - \frac1b\right)$$ which is $$\frac1{2abi}(ab^2+a^2b-b-a)$$

One might then recognise the common factor of $a+b$, and get

$$\frac1{2abi}(a+b)(ab-1)$$

If I distribute the factor of $\frac1{ab}$ evenly between the two brackets, I get

$$\frac1{2i}\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{ab}}\frac{ab-1}{\sqrt{ab}},$$

that is,

$$\frac1{2i}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}}\right)\left(\sqrt{ab} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}}\right).$$

Remembering that $a=e^{ix}$ and $b=e^{iy}$, this is

$$\frac1{2i}\left(\sqrt{e^{i(x-y)}}+\sqrt{e^{-i(x-y)}}\right)\left(\sqrt{e^{i(x+y)}} - \sqrt{e^{-i(x+y)}}\right),$$

that is,

$$\frac1{2i}\left({e^{i\frac{x-y}2}}+{e^{-i\frac{x-y}2}}\right)\left({e^{i\frac{x+y}2}} - {e^{-i\frac{x+y}2}}\right)$$

which gives you the right hand side after just a couple more fairly obvious steps.

Edit: yes, I've glossed over the fact that complex numbers have two square roots, and there's no obvious preference to determine what is meant by $\sqrt{z}$. Defining $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ carefully would give either the desired identity, or $$\sin x+\sin y=2\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}+\pi\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}2+\pi\right)$$

Comment: You might also remark that there is no ambiguity implied in your last equation, since the "angle-addition" formulas allow us to write it as  $$ \sin x \ + \ \sin y \ \ = \ \ 2 \ · \ \left[ \ -\sin \left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right) \ \right] \ · \left[ \ -\cos \left(\frac{x-y}{2} \right) \ \right] \ \ . $$

Answer (score 0):

To begin from the left side using complex exponentials only is "trickier" in the sense that there isn't much in the expression  $ \ \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} + \frac{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}{2i} \ \ $ intrinsically that suggests the result we wish to obtain for the right side of the identity equation.  A proof becomes a matter of arriving at a particular "target" expression. (I don't know that I'd call it "cheating" exactly, as **Michael Hartley** remarks, so much as it is "aiming" to produce a result that isn't clearly motivated from its premise).

Upon adding the two sine terms, the rest becomes a matter of making a specific association and then choosing to impose a factor of $ \ 2 \ $ because that will get you the cosine factor you are after:

$$   \frac{e^{ \ ix} \ - \ e^{ \ -ix}}{2i} \ + \ \frac{e^{ \ iy} \ - \ e^{ \ -iy}}{2i} \ \ = \ \ \frac{e^{ \ ix} \ +  \ e^{ \ iy} \ - \ e^{ \ -ix} \ - \ e^{ \ -iy}}{2i} \ \ ; $$
we decide to compare this numerator with the result of multiplying two binomials
$$ ( \ e^{ \ i·\alpha} \ - \ e^{ \ -i·\alpha} \ ) \ · \ ( \ e^{ \ i·\beta} \ + \ e^{ \ -i·\beta} \ )  \ \ = \ \ e^{ \ i·(\alpha + \beta)} \ + \ e^{ \ i·(\alpha - \beta)} \ - \ e^{ \ -i·(\alpha + \beta)} \ - \ e^{ \ -i·(\alpha - \beta)}  \ \ ; $$

we then identify $ \ x \ = \ \alpha + \ \beta \ $ and $ \ y \ = \ \alpha - \ \beta \ $ and solve the implied system of equations to obtain

$ 2·\alpha \ \ = \ \ x \ + \ y \ \ , \ \ 2·\beta \ \ = \ \ x \ - \ y $

$$ \Rightarrow \ \  \frac{e^{ \ ix} \ - \ e^{ \ -ix}}{2i} \ + \ \frac{e^{ \ iy} \ - \ e^{ \ -iy}}{2i} \ \ = \ \ \frac{( \ e^{ \ i·\alpha}  -  e^{ \ -i·\alpha} \ ) \ · \ ( \ e^{ \ i·\beta}  +  e^{ \ -i·\beta} \ )}{2i}   $$
$$   = \ \ \frac{  e^{ \ i·(x + y)/2}  -  e^{ \ -i·(x + y)/2}   }{2i} \ · \ 2 \ · \  \frac{ e^{ \ i·(x - y)/2}  +  e^{ \ -i·(x - y)/2} }{2} \ \ ;  $$
and thus to our intended trigonometric identity.  (It isn't as much of a "rabbit-out-of-top-hat" proof as some you'll see -- such as introducing a zero/one and turning it into a pair of "canceling" terms/factors -- but this does show why the identity is usually demonstrated by the use of complex numbers going "right-to-left".)

We can do something a bit better "motivated", but it calls for more application of trigonometry.  If we add two numbers with unit modulus, we will generally obtain a sum with non-unit modulus, $ \ e^{ \ ix} + e^{ \ iy} \ = \ s·e^{ \ i·\theta} \ \ . $  On the Argand diagram, this would appear as a triangle as shown in the figure below.  The included angle between the vectors representing these numbers is $ \ \pi - (y - x) \ \ , $ so the Law of Cosines gives us the modulus of the sum as
$$ s^2 \ \ = \ \ 1^2 \ + \ 1^2 \ - \ 2·1·1·\cos( \ \pi - [y - x] \ ) \ \ = \ \ 2 \ · \ [ \ 1 \ + \  \cos( y - x ) \ ] \ \ , $$
which the "cosine-squared" identity $ \ \cos^2 \phi \ = \ \frac12·[ \ 1 + \cos(2 \phi) \ ] \ $ allows us to write as $ \ s^2 \   = \   \ 2 \ · \ 2·\cos^2 \left( \frac{y - x}{2} \right) \ \Rightarrow \ s \ = \ 2·\cos  \left( \frac{y - x}{2} \right) \ \ . $

So our sum to this point is $ \ e^{ \ ix} + e^{ \ iy} \ = \ 2·\cos  \left( \frac{y - x}{2} \right)·e^{ \ i·(x + z)} \ \ . $  We note that our triangle is *isosceles*, so we have $ \ \pi - [y - x] + z + z \ = \ \pi \ \Rightarrow \ z \ = \ \frac{y - x}{2} \ \Rightarrow \ x + z \ = \ \frac{x + y}{2} \ \ . $  Because cosine is an even-symmetry function, we have  $ \ \cos  \left( \frac{y - x}{2} \right) \ = \ \cos  \left( \frac{x - y}{2} \right) \ \ , $ so we may now write our sum as
$$   e^{ \ ix} + e^{ \ iy} \ \ = \ \ (\cos x \ + \ \cos y) \ + \ i·(\sin x \ + \ \sin y) $$
$$ = \ \  2·\cos  \left( \frac{x - y}{2} \right) \ · \  \left[ \ \cos  \left( \frac{x + y}{2} \right)   \ + \ i·\sin  \left( \frac{x + y}{2} \right) \ \right] \ \ .  $$

By identifying the real and imaginary parts of this sum, we at last obtain a "two-fer" of trigonometric identities:
$$ \cos x \ + \ \cos y \ \  = \ \  2 \ · \ \cos  \left( \frac{x + y}{2} \right) \ · \ \cos  \left( \frac{x - y}{2} \right)  $$
and
$$  \sin x \ + \ \sin y \ \ = \ \  2 \ · \ \sin  \left( \frac{x + y}{2} \right) \ · \ \cos  \left( \frac{x - y}{2} \right)  \ \ .  $$

[image]